# C Segmentation Fault within Kali Linux VM

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a C program in a Linux VM that uses a char array. I found that every time I try to do anything to the array, e.g. `sizeof()`, I get a segmentation fault. I wrote a test program that just made an array and got `sizeof()` as a test, and sure enough I get the same error.
I think this is related to the program running in a VM. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARR_LENGTH(x) sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])

int main()
{
    printf("Hllo world!\n");
    int sent = 10;
    char hello[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'};
    printf(sizeof(hello));
    printf(ARR_LENGTH(hello));
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something, or is the VM likely the problem?

Comment: `printf(sizeof(hello));` is not how you print a number. `printf` will use that number as a `char*`, which most likely causes the segmentation fault. I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about it.

Comment: … And no, this has nothing to do with it running in a VM. (Quite curious about how you reached that conclusion.)

Comment: It is a good idea to read the man-page for standard functions you use before using them or suspecting the OS. And a VM will have impact on applications code at all. That's the fundamental idea of using one.

Comment: @Biffen I came to the conclusion as I had no other explanation, and as it was a memory issue I thought it may be due to some memory management problems. However I did not think about `printf()` being the problem, I made the fatal mistake of assuming it took any argument like Java with `String.out.println()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to read the [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) documentation carefully. It doesn't take an integer as its first argument.

The problematic lines are:

```
 printf(sizeof(hello));
 printf(ARR_LENGTH(hello));
```

It should be:

```
 printf("%zu\n", sizeof(hello));
 printf("%zu\n", ARR_LENGTH(hello));
```

(`%zu` is the format specifier to print `size_t` values).

My gcc compiler produces the warning:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer
> without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

for those two statements. Up the compiler warning levels (in case you don't get them alrready).

Comment: This doesn't fix the original code I have, but it fixes the code in this question so I'll accept it. Useful to know at any rate :) Thanks!